# Online math writing with Latex

Tags: math-mode

How can I write math with Latex on different websites or on social media? I mean you write some latex code but the output is mathematics. Should I install something?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). Old yet good. I often download the png image generated and upload it to the website/email I send. Whether or not a website (internet forum for example) supports math is mainly dependent on the website software they are using.

Comment: @tush I'll check it. There is something called Mathjax. Can it do what I want?

Comment: mathjax requires that it is installed on the website you want to use it on.